# Call by Value or reference for list of Integer Call?

Tags: apex

Can someone please help me to know why I am getting below value in debug log:

The values for below debug log are:
'A','B','C'
null

```
public class TestingClass{


public void myfunc1(){
List<String> stringList1 =  new List<String>{'A','C','B'};
List<String>  stringList2 = sortStringList(stringList1);
system.debug(stringList1); 
system.debug(stringList2);
}

public List<String> sortStringList(List<String> stringListVal){
stringListVal.sort();
stringListVal = null;
return stringListVal;
}
}
```

Comment: This is fully covered in the documentation. See [this blog entry](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html) for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the blog post mentioned in [@Phil W](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/50252/phil-w)'s comment, understanding the following line from your code snippet could be helpful.

```
stringListVal = null;
```

`null` is neither an object nor a type, but just a special value that can be assigned to any reference type. When you assign null to any variable, you are telling the underlying engine to remove the reference to the existing object and point it to null reference (which is also synonymous to the variable pointing to nothing). In apex, any variable declared but not initialized automatically points to null reference [like this code: `List<String> ls;`].

In your code, `stringList1` from `myfunc1` & `stringListVal` from `sortStringList`, both point to the same memory location or object until `stringListVal = null;` is executed. As soon as this code is executed, the existing object reference for `stringListVal` is removed and a null reference is assigned. But the memory location (where the list actually resides) itself is not cleared, implying that `stringList1` is still pointing to the same location. In the next line `return stringListVal;`, you are returning an object with null reference which is assigned to `List<String>  stringList2` [Note that this is same as executing `List<String>  stringList2;` or `List<String>  stringList2 = null;`]

Now, if you replaced `stringListVal = null;` with `stringListVal.clear();`, you'll see that both the debug statements are returning an empty list i.e., `()`. This is because the clear method is actually deleting the list entries from the memory location.

Comment: Thanks Arut, after phil and your comments, it has been so much easier to understand.